# Magento2 Sitemap URLs 301 Redirecting

Tags: redirect, seo, magento2, sitemap

Currently, we have a Magento2 website which contains a vast amount of product URL's that are 301 redirecting upon categories applied to them.

The issue with this is, that this is causing errors to be flagged relating to incorrect URL's within the sitemap, which will cause issues from a technical SEO perspective.

Is this an issue which has been come across before? And if so, is there any way to amend the configuration to rectify this?

I'm fairly new to Magento, and such would like some guidance/clarity over  this would be greatly appreciated. :-)